Kubuntu 24.04 - sound problem, first second is always missing
Since upgrading to 24.04 my Ubuntu does not transmit the first second of every sound I play, either video, stream, Audio control panel text or else.
Seems to me like a weird standby/energy saving configuration as I can see this also happening if I pause a video for a few minutes. This is very annoying, especially for trading alerts and notifications.
My sound card is recognized without problems as before with Kubuntu 20.04. I am using optical out. Maybe it has something to do with this. So far I could not find any useful config.

Are you using a presentation app when this happens? I have the same issue and I'm trying to rule out L.O. Impress. It's as if the audio handler has shut down and needs a second or so to wake up.
